# Grouping an array by type in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

Say I have this array of objects:

```
        var input = new object[]
        { 
            "Hello",
            123,                
            true,
            "Hats",
            12,34,
            '!'
        };
```

Which I then want to group by types and then return a dictionary with the type as the key and the number of occurrences of each type as the value. How would I go about doing this? I've got the array into a dictionary now, but from here I'm a little stuck as to what to do with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply group by `Type`, and use `ToDictionary` method:

```
input.GroupBy(x => x.GetType()).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

Usually, when you are using `GroupBy` to group based on a reference type you need either override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method on the type, or implement a custom comparer to get the expected behaviour. But fortunutely, the `Type` class is already doing that. So this will work as expected.